# How to disable accessibility support for the divider of a NSSplitView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, nssplitview

I have a `NSSplitView` in my app. Its divider position is fixed, the user is not able to drag the divider around. Now I am adding support for accessibility. When using VoiceOver, the user can select & drag the divider. That breaks my UI. 
How can I tell VoiceOver, that it should ignore the divider?

I am using the new Accessibility Protocol available since OS X 10.10.

Setting `splitView.isAccessibilityElement` or `splitView.isAccessibilityEnabled` to `no` does not work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I asked a nice guy from the AppKit team at WWDC.
He told me that this is not possible at the moment - because I can not acces the `divider` within the `splitView`.

**Explanation**:
Disabling the accessibility support on a `NSView`, makes the particular view inaccessible, but not its sub view - which is the desired behavior normally

Since the divider is a subview of `NSSplitView`, this does not work.

**Solution**:
I ended up not using `NSSplitView` anymore because I don't need any of the class specific features. The dividers are fixed in my application.

Instead I used `NSStackView` to encapsulate my subviews - and it works perfectly.  (Hide and show subviews)